# How to delete input binding in input system unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue to delete bindings in input system unity.
I know how to rebind and add binding with code but can't delete bindings with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove an input binding from an input action using one of these methods:

```
action.ChangeBinding(...).Erase();
action.ChangeBindingWithId(...).Erase();
action.ChangeBindingWithPath(...).Erase();
action.ChangeBindingWithGroup(...).Erase();
```

## Example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputAction action = new InputAction();

    private void Start()
    {
        action.AddBinding("<Keyboard>/#(a)");
        action.performed += OnActionPerformed;
        action.Enable();
    }

    private void OnActionPerformed(InputAction.CallbackContext e)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Action performed: {e.control.name}");
        action.ChangeBinding(0).Erase();
    }
}
```